# SonarQube+Github: conditional SQ scan for pull requests?

Tags: github, sonarqube

I have SonarQube integrated with GitHub, so my PRs would have the check for SQ, however there are certain PRs that I need to bypass SQ scan, is there an easy way for doing this?

edit: I know how to configure SQ to scan or not scan branches, but Github expects SQ result to make the PR mergeable, is there something on Github I need to tweak?

Thanks!